# Как удалить cоответствующий элемент из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить из списка элемент, который соответствует вводимому значению:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
user = int(input(''))# 2
if user in a:
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == user:
        del a[i]
print(a) # [1,2]
```

Он удалит элемент с индексом 2 т.е. 3, а мне надо, чтобы он удалил элемент 2, который вводит пользователь. Как это сделать, подскажите?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).
Данный метод удаляет первый элемент в списке, имеющий значение переданного аргумента.

***Пример:***

```py
li = [1, 2, 3]
inp = int(input())  # 2

if inp in li:
    li.remove(inp)

print(li)           # [1, 3]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

если список элементов уникальный

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
user = int(input(''))# 2
if user in a and a.count(user) == 1:
    del a[a.index(user)]
print(a) # [1,2]
```

если элементы повторяются будут "косяки"

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
inp = int(input())  # 2
a[:] = [a for a in a if a != inp]
print(a) # [1,3]
```

Comment: Круто! Оказывается и так можно!